# serving static content and java web apps from one server

Tags: java, html, web, server

I'm trying to build my own site where initially I will only host my profile and resume but will also build and publish some simple web applications that I can use as coding samples for jobs. The idea is people can see a demo of the apps and then see the code on github.

Can I do all this using only tomcat or should I use another server for this purpose?

I have heard that tomcat should only be used for java web applications but I've tried it locally and it seems to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally do it all with tomcat.

Arguably, tomcat is not as efficient as apache or ngnix for serving static assets, 10% less so, and does not scale as well. There's a good article on the subject here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.2-doc/tomcat-apache-howto.html

This is not not going to be an issue for you with a small site. Go with what gets you up and running the fastest.

If you want, later you can show off your technical prowess by running tomcat  behind a web server. You can tell folks at interviews the story.